# How to trim specific text with grep

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I am in need of trimming some text with grep, I have tried various other methods and havn't had much luck, so for example:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\report2011.docx: My Report 2011
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\newposter.docx: Dinner Party Poster 08
```

How would it be possible to trim the text file, so to trim the ":" and all characters after it.

E.g. so the output would be like:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\report2011.docx
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\newposter.docx
```

Comment: You have to do it just with grep?

Comment: @George Kastrinis Well something like it, GNU and all..

Comment: If you can use GNU tools try `cut`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use awk?

```
awk -F: '{print $1':'$2}' inputFile > outFile
```

you can use grep
(note that -o returns only the matching text)

```
grep -oe "^C:[^:]" inputFile > outFile
```

Answer (score 5):

That is pretty simple to do with `grep -o`:

```
$ grep -o '^C:[^:]*' input
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\report2011.docx
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\newposter.docx
```

If you can have other drives just replace `C` by `.`:

```
$ grep -o '^.:[^:]*' input
```

If a line can start with something different than a drive name, you can consider both the occurrence a drive name in the beginning of the line and the case where there is no such drive name:

```
$ grep -o '^\(.:\|\)[^:]*' input
```

Answer (score 3):

`cat inputFile | cut -f1,2 -d":"`

The `-d` specifies your delimiter, in this case ":".  The `-f1,2` means you want the first and second fields.

The first part doesn't necessarily have to be `cat inputFile`, it's just whatever it takes to get the text that you referred to.  The key part being `cut -f1,2 -d":"`

Comment: this will eliminate the first ':' in C:/ also, no need to cat and pipe cut -f1,2 -d":" inputFile should work

Comment: @matchew, it seems like it would get rid of the first ":" but it's not for me.  Weird.

Comment: so I just tried it, and your right. It does not remove the first : this threw me. and then i tried -f1,3 and noticed that both :'s remained. I guess cut worked differently than I thought. +1 for you =)

Comment: @matchew, Thanks.  It surprised me too, but then again I've mostly used space and tab for for delimiters so I probably would have noticed.  FYI, you can use the argument `--output-delimiter=STRING` to output anything in place of the delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

Your text looks like output of grep. If what you're asking is how to print filenames matching a pattern, use GNU grep option --files-with-matches

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as well for your example

```
grep -E -o "^C\S+"| tr -d ":"
egrep -o "^C\S+"| tr -d ":"
```

\S here is non-space character match